# Having trouble applying style to unordered lists

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have never had a problem with this in the past. For one reason or another, I cannot figure out how to do the following (jsFiddle included).

1. Add bullets to the list (they are not showing up).
2. Add styling to the list, so that the bullets of the list do not over lap the border of the div container of which they are inside.

These are both very basic desires, however something is just not right with what I am producing.

Please take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DyeUy/7/) for more details.

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: Uncheck the "normalized CSS" option in jsFiddle. What you are seeing isn't normal behavior; the padding and margins have been removed from the elements by default using a "normalization" stylesheet. Alternatively, add the padding back to the `ul`. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/5bqgz/

Comment: You're close to being correct. However, I've found jsFiddle to not display lists properly. Use http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp as a reference. *Hint: use the 'Try it yourself >>' buttons for more examples.

Comment: @CoryLarson: D'OH! I never knew that check box was there! I think you've just saved me some frustration for in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `padding-left` to your `<ul>`, as the bullet points are being chopped off.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DyeUy/11/

This article is a bit dated, but still a great one to look at for help with lists: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/